# ASP.NET 4.0 silenty ignores control classname containing two dashes ( eg "hint--left" )

Tags: asp.net, css, class, attributes

Adding "hint-left" to myControl.Attributes["class"] produces the corresponding class name when the control is rendered. 
However, "hint--left" - as is used by the css-only tooltip framework I'm using, is silently ignored - and not rendered.

Bit ridiculous - we're using this style of class naming all over the place. Can't find anything saying this is naughty or bad.

Why?

Comment: I simply can't believe this! Even when I override the render method of the control and spit out a raw string - the HtmlTextWriter strips out the class name!

Comment: oops ... ummm.... long week ;-)

Comment: Hey, did you ever get to the bottom of this? We're having the same problem...

Comment: I may have used some js to walk the Dom and replace the class names?